# Подскажите, почему не работают картинки на open server? предполагаю, что дело в url, экспериментировал, всё равно не работало

Tags: css, html5, sass

```css
.promo {
    min-height: 620px;
    background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) ), url(../img/bg/bg1.jpg) center (center/cover) no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    &__header {
        padding-top: 110px;
        text-align: center;
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: 700;
    }
    &__subheader {
        padding-top: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    &__descr {
        margin-top: 30px;
        display: block;
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: 'Roboto';
        line-height: 40px;
        padding-left: 50px;
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        font-weight: 700;
    }
    .scheme {
        position: absolute;
        right: 25%;
        bottom: 190px;
        padding-left: 50px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Отредактируйте код с помощью [кнопки править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1145511/edit).

Comment: Я редактирую код  в vscode, перезапускаю сервер, нажимаю на "код страницы", а там изменения не появились(именно определенные изменения url), не понимаю, что за кнопка править), не представляете как сложно самому разбираться во куче всех легких проблем, которые можно решить за 5 минут, а я трачу по 1-3 часа